# Divisibility of order of odd primes

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, abelian-groups

[image]

[image]

I am having hard time showing the above. I thought of using Euler's criterion but I can not proceed from $q-1\nmid w_n/2$ and $p-1| w_n/2$

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information that is not contained in accessible portions of your post and that is required in order to understand your query. [See here for an explanation of why this is frowned upon](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: What text is this from?

Comment: @Shaun not from a text. they are excercise problems